# Storybook Auto Doc (v7) is NOT reading the default props & prop types from component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, webpack-5, storybook-addon-doc

How can I render my default props and prop type in stories, which are configured in component file? Currently my stories are appearing but without the default props & prop types in Doc.

Attaching the snapshot.. Please help me I am new to React-Storybook & Webpack.

PS: I am using webpack5 react18 storybook7

[image: storybook-auto-doc-without-props]